# Javascript Get image of building from google

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building out a map using html/css/jquery to plot locations with an image of that location, returned to me by an internal API. In most cases the api will return to me an image URL. In some cases the api does not return to me any image. In those cases I need to get the image from google.  I know I need to deal with the cases where 'ImageURL' is null. I need some guidance how to accomplish this.

Thank you so much!

Here is a small excerpt from my code where I use the image returned from the api,

```
     fetch('https://api/id)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
        const mapClassToResponse = {
            '.background': 'ImageURL',
        };
        Object.keys(mapClassToResponse).map(k => {

            $(k).html(r[mapClassToResponse[k]]);
        });
 });
```

Comment: Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this to help others. 
I verified that what I wanted to use was deprecated. 
I was trying to use the google image search api which was deprecated.
What I am doing as an alternative is storing locally in an image folder an image for each location that I will potentially want to display. 
In the cases where no image is returned to me from the API I will use an image from this folder.
Please note I am not dealing with so many locations, under 200, so this approach is possible for me.